# How to use Action Link in Option tag to send parameters to the controller

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm using a Select tag and I have `foreach` that adds the values to the list, but I have to call an Update Controller and pass it 2 parameters using `ActionLink`. I tried to do it this way but it doesn't work. I wanted to know what I'm doing wrong?

```
<form action="Update " method="get" class="select-menu">
<select id="sectionId"
        name="sectionId"
        class="selectpicker"
        title="Section"
        data-width="100%"
        data-live-search="true"
        onchange="this.form.submit()">

       @foreach (var item in Model)
       {
           <option value="@item.Text" data-url="@Html.ActionLink(item.Text, "UpdateBoard", new { subSectionID = item.Value, subsectionName = item.Text })"></option>
       }
  </select>
</form>
```

The query should be something like this `http://localhost:60082/Update?subSectionID=27&subsectionName=Something`

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `select` tag inside the `form` in way described above will not work properly because of the `form` doesn't have additional parameters for the route (*`subSectionID`* and *`subsectionName`*). As result, the `Update` action method will receiving  `subSectionID` and `subsectionName` parameters as `null`.

Therefore, to make these parameters be set dynamically depend on a selection try the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#sectionId').change(function () {
        var url = $(this).val();
        if (url != null && url != '') {
            window.location.href = url;
        }
    })

</script>

<select id="sectionId"
        name="sectionId"
        class="selectpicker"
        title="Section"
        data-width="100%"
        data-live-search="true">

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <option value="@Url.Action("SetLanguage", new { subSectionID = item.Value, subsectionName = item.Text })">@item.Text</option>
    }
</select>
```

Inside the `foreach` use `Url.Action` helper instead of the `Html.ActionLink`. The `Url.Action` helper generates a fully qualified URL to an action method by using the specified action name and route values.

But the `Html.ActionLink` returns an anchor element for the specified link text, action and this may cause additional problems when will be passed to the server side.